# DocumentNode.SelectNodes returns null - HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I want to obtain the IMDB rating of different movies stored in **span** tags of Html source code. For that, I am trying to use Html parsing to collect data from HTML span tags. Everything is working fine until SelectNodes() method of DocumentNode is called which is returning null.

I know this question has been asked a numerous times before but despite doing a lot of research and trying out different solutions, I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with my code. It's really really important for me to to solve this problem in order to complete my semester project so any kind of help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
string url = "https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=into+the+wild&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8";

        StreamReader sourceCode = makeHttpRequest(url);
        //makeRequest() returns the html source code of the url
        String sourceCodeString = sourceCode.ReadToEnd();

        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(sourceCodeString);
        var itemList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='_tvg']")
                .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keypoint here is setting a user-agent.

Below code returns 3 results, if you remove `User-Agent` you will get a null value...

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
    var html = await client.GetStringAsync("https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&q=into+the+wild&sourceid=opera&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8");
    var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(html);
    var result = doc.DocumentNode
                    .SelectNodes("//span[@class='_tvg']")
                    .Select(p => p.InnerText)
                    .ToList();


}
```

Comment: I've used the above code but after the statement
 var html = await client.GetStringAsync(" ");
the program terminates (without throwing any exception) and the remaining statements are not executed. Could you please explain the reason for this?

Comment: @KhursandShakeel Just create an empty winforms project paste this code to *Form_Load* and try again (don't forget to mark the method as async) BTW: you may want to use a try/catch block...

Comment: I marked the method with async and also put a try/catch block but still no success. 
BTW I'm working on console application instead of windows form application as I've never worked on winforms application. Can't it be done on console application?

Comment: @KhursandShakeel Console apps has no *syncronization context*, so instead of using *await*,  use `var html = client.GetStringAsync(...).Result`.

Comment: @ L.B It totally worked! Seriously I can't thank you enough for helping me out :)